# Как получить и использовать значение в Firebase вне ValueEventListener

Tags: android, firebase

Всем привет!
Я пишу `android`-приложение, суть которого в том, что пользователи могут добавлять маркеры на гугл-карту. Сейчас хочу прописать условие, чтобы пользователи могли редактировать описание только своих маркеров, а чужих - нет.

Регистрация и аутентификация происходит через `email` с помощью `google firebase`. При создании маркера и добавлении его в базу данных туда же добавляется строка с `userID`. При попытке изменить описание маркера, система должна делать проверку, залогинился ли пользователь.

**Суть проблемы:** Проверка `userID` конкретного маркера возможна только через базу данных, для его получения и сохранения в строку используется следующий код:

```
public class DialogDescription extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

public static String userID;
public static Marker currentMarker;


@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

     MarkersDataBase.mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

            MarkersDataBase.mDatabase.child("Markers").child(key).child("userID").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        userID = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                        currentMarker.setTitle(userID); //Сюда данные передаются нормально, это просто для примера, по идее, тут этой строки вообще нет
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                currentMarker.setTitle(userID); // Сюда userID уже приходит как null.

   }
}
```

Но у меня не получается передать полученное значение `userID` во вне new `ValueEventListener`, оно обнуляется. Возможно ли это? Если нет, как лучше сделать проверку на соответствие `userID` в маркере (записано в базу данных, а не сам маркер) и `userID` текущего пользователя, вошедшего в приложение?

Comment: добавьте пжл код, где у вас "обнуляется" userID.

Comment: Добавил, посмотрите, плиз

Comment: A userID только по клику должен появляться?

Comment: Все действо происходит после клика на InfoWindow маркера. Я снова не весь код выложил, там такая простыня, что разобраться может занять время. Но это главное - убрал обработчики кнопок диалога и прочее

Answer (score 1):

Да действительно, не покидает значение блока `onClick`

Сделал у себя так

Создал метод

```
private String doResult(String result) {
    userID = result;//здесь глобальной переменной присваиваем значение переданное в параметре
    //do something
    Log.i("LOG_TAG", "userID " + userID);
    return userID;
}
```

Можно и не возвращать значение - второй вариант метода

```
private void doResult(String result) {
    userID = result;//здесь глобальной переменной присваиваем значение переданное в параметре
    //do something
    Log.i("LOG_TAG", "userID " + userID);
}
```

Теперь строку

```
userID = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
```

меняем на вызов метода `doResult` и передаем ему значение. Теперь глобальная переменная `userID` не `null`.

```
doResult(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
```

*P.S. можно усовершенствовать/оптимизировать наверняка*

Comment: Вроде бы заработало, спасибо! Но почему так? Зачем нужна обертка в виде метода? Я, в силу малого опыта, не вижу тут принципиальной разницы, объясните плиз!

Comment: @Glavvredina: Видимо что-то связано с ассинхронностью исполнения callback`ами. Пока что мои догадки.

Comment: Все-таки не совсем верно работает, но теперь я с помощью логов везде, где только можно, отловил, почему так. У меня сначала отрабатывает последняя строка приведенного куска кода, а только потом то, что связано с обращением с базой данных. Поэтому сначала передается null, а потом userID с запозданием на ход. Как это исправить? Синхронизация нужна какая-то? Как ее лучше оформить?

Comment: @Glavvredina: null у вас при загрузке Activity(DialogFragment) появляется? сложно вот так без полной картины вам помочь.